# How to calculate the age of a feedburner item link?

Tags: php, datetime, rss, feedburner

I am working on a project to determinate the age of a url/post listed in a feedburner feed. I can parse, and get the pubDate value in a format like this: `Sat, 13 Jul 2013 10:00:15 +0000`

I would like to create a PHP script that subtract the original datetime from the current one. I already created `strtotime($item->pubDate)`, but I am confused by the time zones. The script must work with every feed (maybe in different time zones), and the script must be work properly from every timezone.

So how can I determine the age of the post based on these specifications?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11896631/342740

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class for this, specifically the static method [`DateTime::createFromFormat()'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), something like this:-

```
$dateStr = 'Sat, 13 Jul 2013 10:00:15 +0000';
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $dateStr);
$dateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($dateTime);
$diff = $dateTime->diff(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
var_dump($diff);
```

Output:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-07-13 10:00:15' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 22
  public 'i' => int 47
  public 's' => int 48
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 0
```

As you can see each dateTime object has had its timezone set to UTC. `$diff` is an instance of [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) which represents the difference between 'now' and the date you received.

You can output the difference between the dates in any format you wish using ['DateInterval::format()'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)