# PHP: Convert ISO8601 Offset To Actual Time Zone

Tags: php, datetime

I'm connecting to an JSON event API that returns schedule information in ISO8601 format.

```
"schedule": [
{
    "datetime": "2014-06-02T19:30:00-04:00",
    "speaker": "Keith Moore"
},
{
    "datetime": "2014-06-03T19:30:00-04:00",
    "speaker": "Phyllis Moore"
]
```

When I `echo date("c", strtotime($schedule[$j]["datetime"]));` I get 2014-06-02T18:30:00-05:00.  Of course, that makes sense since `date()` uses the server's time zone.

If I pass a time zone to `date()`, or use `date_default_timezone_set`), then it should fix things up.  Unfortunately, there is no specification as to what the time zone is in ISO8610 (just the offset).  If I try and get the time zone from the ISO8601 date, using `date()`, then the time zone goes back to the server's.

What I want to do is show the date/time/time zone that's local to the event (Eastern Daylight Time, in this instance).  Is there a way to do this?

A couple options that I have thought of, but neither seems appropriate...

Since I have control over the API, I could send the schedule information in RFC 822 format (Mon, 02 Jun 2014 19:30:00 EDT).  That would give me hooks that I could do...

```
if ($pubDatetimezone == "PST" || $pubDatetimezone == "PDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "MST" || $pubDatetimezone == "MDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "CST" || $pubDatetimezone == "CDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
if ($pubDatetimezone == "EST" || $pubDatetimezone == "EDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");
```

...but ISO8601 just seems like a more appropriate format.

On the other hand, I could do some overly-complex array where I specify every possible date/offset combination with a time zone.  That, definitely, seems like too much work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered PHP's DateTime class to help you solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't know it existed.  Can it determine a time zone from the offset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC offset to timezone or date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820718/convert-utc-offset-to-timezone-or-date)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate notice.  I hadn't seen that thread.  I'll read up.

Comment: @vascowhite That may be the trick.  I saw `timezone_name_from_abbr()`, but I thought it converted from the actual abbreviation (like CST), which I didn't know.

Answer (score 6):

You should use PHP's DateTime. Since ISO8601 is an international standard, PHP supports it. The code you need is the following:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2014-06-03T19:30:00-04:00');
```

You can specify the third parameter, a DateTimeZone object which you can use to further offset the given date.

For example, if you wanted to use GMT -4 to be GMT

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2014-06-03T19:30:00-04:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

And after that, all that's left is:

```
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y, H:i:s'); // format is the same as for date() function.
```

Comment: But that's the problem.  I don't know what the actual time zone is.  -04:00 could be EDT or AST.  I do have location information (City and State), but there are multiple states that contain two time zones (not to mention all the foreign countries that I have no idea about.

Comment: The datetime object gives you the offset `($dt->getOffset())`. If you want a time zone to which the offset corresponds, using something like `echo timezone_name_from_abbr("", 3600 * $dt->getOffset(), 0);` should give you something meaningful.

Comment: `$dt->getOffset()` did what I was looking for.  It is having a problem with a schedule in Abuja, Nigeria, though.  I have a date/time of `2013-11-01T18:00:00+01:00` and it's outputting `Europe/London`.  I'm sure the problem is with the lack of daylight saving time in West Africa Time.  I could specify an override for anything that is wacky.

Comment: That wouldn't work. The documentation for [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) states "The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the datetime parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00)"

Answer (score -1):

The answers that were given, while good and very helpful, still left too many exceptions that weren't accounted for (outputting the wrong time zone abbreviation, even though the offset is the same).

Since I have control of the API, I simply included a time zone field.

```
"schedule": [
{
    "datetime": "2013-08-02T18:30:00-05:00",
    "timezone": "CDT",
    "speaker": "Happy Caldwell"
}
]
```

Then, when consuming that data, I simply did a comparison and set the server to that time zone.

```
if ($timezone == "HAST" || $timezone == "HADT") date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Honolulu");
if ($timezone == "AKST" || $timezone == "AKDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Juneau");
if ($timezone == "PST" || $timezone == "PDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
if ($timezone == "MST" || $timezone == "MDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Boise");
// doesn't observe dst
if ($state == "AZ") date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
if ($timezone == "CST" || $timezone == "CDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
if ($timezone == "EST" || $timezone == "EDT") date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
// doesn't observe dst
if ($timezone == "PET") date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");
if ($timezone == "AST" || $timezone == "ADT") date_default_timezone_set("America/Puerto_Rico");
// doesn't observe dst
if ($timezone == "GMT") date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
if ($timezone == "CET" || $timezone == "CEST") date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
// doesn't observe dst
if ($timezone == "WAT") date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
```

Now, I'm sure there is a much better way to do this (probably with `DateTime`).  Feel free to comment on better ways to perform the same function.  This does do what was needed, though.

Of course, this doesn't help someone that ONLY has the time zone offset.  In those instances, you may have to use one of the other answers and just deal with the exceptions.

Comment: -1 as this answer solves the OP's problem, but does not answer the question asked (yes, I know that the poster is the OP). If the OP would accept or post an answer that actually answers the question, then I'll remove the -1.

Comment: Ouch...I understand the rules.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is an answer.  A comment to the original post would have probably been more appropriate, but could you imaging that code post in a comment?  Yikes.