# Getting the timezone identifier for date_default_timezone_set?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm trying to use `date_default_timezone_set()` in PHP, which accepts a [timezone identifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) as the only parameter.

How do I get the timezone identifier using only the time offset obtained with javascript, such as:

```
var visitortime = new Date();
timezone = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset();
```

So now in PHP, I have for example:

```
$timezone = -120;
```

How do I use my `$timezone` with `date_default_timezone_set()` at this point?

I was trying to go by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896631/616855), however I'm not sure how to properly set the third parameter for `date_default_timezone_set()` -- the `isdst` parameter.

How do I know whether it's 0 or 1, depending on only the value obtained from javascript, in my case `-120`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot identify the timezone simply by knowing the offset from UTC time, because a timezone definition also contains daylight saving time switch dates.

For example, in America, Nevada and Arizona currently have the same time, and the same offset (-0700) from UTC, but Nevada is in the US/Pacific timezone, and Arizona is in America/Phoenix and has no daylight saving.

Go ask your user about it.

Comment: This answer is correct, but there are some things you can do about it in JavaScript.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526897/634824).