# Finding midnight of a timezone given offset in minutes [PHP]

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I have an offset from UTC stored in minutes: e.g -240

I'm trying to find the corresponding UNIX timestamp of midnight of the current day for this particular offset.

I found similar information in questions like this one: [How do I get the UTC time of "midnight" for a given timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373370/how-do-i-get-the-utc-time-of-midnight-for-a-given-timezone)

However, I don't have the city name/timezone jurisdiction, just a minute offset. I think this should be fine since for my purposes I don't need to account for daylight savings, it can be off by an hour and still be fine.

**Examples**

Offset: -420

Midnight on 7/12/2014: 1405148400 (unix TS)

With UTC, I would have to first tell if it's the next day or same day as the TZ because it may have a different "last midnight".

Comment: Get UTC time (today, 0:00), and subtract 240 minutes?

Comment: That won't give me the midnight of that timezone. That'll give me some time before or after midnight UTC, which isn't exactly the same thing. :/

Comment: Could you give a couple of examples just to make sure I'm interpreting this correctly, because John's answer sounds about right?

Comment: Actually, I struggled understanding the problem myself. My comment seems perfectly accurate, yet there may be a few things I didn't quite get...

Comment: I added an example. Does it help? :S

Comment: The main problem I have is that the last midnight that occurred can be different between the two.

Comment: I could simply subtract/add the offset to midnight UTC if the last midnight to occur wasn't on a different date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to think through it quite a bit, but I think this was the solution I was looking for. Let me know if you think this algorithm is incorrect.

```
function getLastMidnightForOffset( $minuteOffset ) {
    $today = mktime( 0, 0, 0 );
    $tomorrow = $today + 86400;
    $yesterday = $today - 86400;
    $offset = $minuteOffset * 60;

    if ( time() + $offset >= $tomorrow ) {
        $localMidnight = $tomorrow - $offset;
    } elseif ( time() + $offset >= $today ) {
        $localMidnight = $today - $offset;
    } else {
        $localMidnight = $yesterday - $offset;
    }

    return $localMidnight;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` and why do you have `$today + $offset` - should that be a minus?

Comment: updated, after testing. my default/server time is already set to UTC though.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution looks a little ugly it does do what I think you're asking for! This example uses -180 minutes as the offset.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Work out which day the time zone is in
$day = strtotime('-180 minutes');

// Strip of the time part of the day, to give UTC midnight on the correct day
$utcMidnight = strtotime('midnight', $day);

// Now apply the offset in reverse to give the zone's midnight
$zoneMidnight = strtotime('+180 minutes', $utcMidnight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `date_default_timezone_set` to make all time-related functions acknowledge the shift. First thing to do is to convert those minutes into hours, since the UTC gap is 1 hour between n and n+1.

```
$hours = $minutes / 60;
```

I would also recommend that you check the minutes values first :

```
if($minutes % 60 == 0) // We're good.
```

Now, if you want to convert the UTC offset to a timezone, you can create your function :

```
<?php
function offsetToTimezone($offset){
    $timezones = array( 
        "-12" => "Pacific/Kwajalein", 
        "-11" => "Pacific/Samoa", 
        "-10" => "Pacific/Honolulu", 
        "-9" => "America/Juneau", 
        "-8" => "America/Los_Angeles", 
        "-7" => "America/Denver", 
        "-6" => "America/Mexico_City", 
        "-5" => "America/New_York", 
        "-4" => "America/Caracas", 
        "-3.5" => "America/St_Johns", 
        "-3" => "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires", 
        "-2" => "Atlantic/Azores",
        "-1" => "Atlantic/Azores", 
        "0" => "Europe/London", 
        "1" => "Europe/Paris", 
        "2" => "Europe/Helsinki", 
        "3" => "Europe/Moscow", 
        "3.5" => "Asia/Tehran", 
        "4" => "Asia/Baku", 
        "4.5" => "Asia/Kabul", 
        "5" => "Asia/Karachi", 
        "5.5" => "Asia/Calcutta", 
        "6" => "Asia/Colombo", 
        "7" => "Asia/Bangkok", 
        "8" => "Asia/Singapore", 
        "9" => "Asia/Tokyo", 
        "9.5" => "Australia/Darwin", 
        "10" => "Pacific/Guam", 
        "11" => "Asia/Magadan", 
        "12" => "Asia/Kamchatka" 
    );

    return $timezones[$offset];
}
?>
```

... and use if for conversion :

```
date_default_timezone_set(offsetToTimezone($hours));
```

By the way, I suggest you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11896631/2228310), which provides you with a more elegant way to achieve the work of `offsetToTimezone`.

Now that your script if configured on the correct timezone, just ask for a timestamp :

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0);
```

If at some time, you need to reset to timezone to default, you might need `date_default_timezone_get` to save it :

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
// Change to another timezone based on your offset.
// Get your timestamp.
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```

Comment: A good answer but a couple of things are not accounted for - there are timezones that don't have a whole hour offset (some are 30 minutes or 45 minutes), and an offset can't be mapped to a city like this with any accuracy - the city will have DST rules that are different from others with the same standard offset.

Comment: The TZ lookup was the only solution I could think of, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to go that route, by using an internal function.

Comment: I am afraid the lack of accuracy may come the language itself, and its timezones support : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. The *Others* category may give you more convenient alternatives, yet most of them (not UTC) are deprecated. You may have to fallback to direct calculation (subtracting the offset yourself).

Comment: The Etc/GMT+X options are the best bet because they don't have DST, but only for the 60 minute zones.