# Strange behaviour with DateTime and DateTimeZone

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, timezone

This is a follow up question on my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182756/get-proper-time-from-client-supplied-timestamp-and-timezone).  The app is javascript/php.  In Javascript, I'm getting the local timestamp and timezone offset:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
var tzoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

I am testing this from London and the time I am passing in represents 15:30:00 GMT.

I then pass these to a php script on the server, which needs to format this timestamp as H:MM:SS (i.e., php's `format('h:i:s', $time)`.  I started in PHP with this code:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp / 1000);  //javascript includes milliseconds, php doesn't
echo $dt->format('h:i:s');
```

This produced output of `07:30:00` - which is the same point in time but using the server's timezone (server is in California).

I then used the trick from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820718/convert-utc-offset-to-timezone-or-date) to get the timezone and set that timezone

```
$tz = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $tzoffset * 60, true);  //javascript's offset is in seconds
if($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $tzoffset * 60, false);
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($tz));
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp / 1000);
echo $dt->format('h:i:s');
```

This produced a rather strange result of `02:30:00`.

I then changed the above to simply have:

```
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp / 1000);
echo $dt->format('h:i:s');
```

This produced the result `03:30:00`.

How do I get the server to output `15:30:00` based on the information the client supplies?

**EDIT:** Thanks, @MarkM, this was rather stupid of me - however this still doesn't completely solve the problem, as this code:

```
$tz = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $tzoffset * 60, true);  //javascript's offset is in seconds
if($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $tzoffset * 60, false);
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($tz));
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp / 1000);
echo $dt->format('h:i:s');
```

now produces `14:30:00`, that is, it doesn't take into account DST.  Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT 2:** I forgot that javascript's `getTimezoneOffset` returns the inverse (i.e. how many minutes the GMT is from the current time).  I added this one line at the top of the code in my *EDIT* and it's now working correctly:

```
$tzoffset = -$tzoffset;
```

Comment: Change `'h:i:s'` to `'H:i:s'`

Comment: @MarkM Thanks! This got me a step closer, but still not quite there yet.  Please see my update in the question.

Comment: @MarkM Never mind, found the issue - forgot that javascript's `getTimezoneOffset` returns the inverse value.  Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format the hour to 24 hour format, use the capital H.

Change `'h:i:s'` to `'H:i:s'`