# how to convert facebook's userinfo timzone field to Time Zone name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timezone, timezone-offset

I am getting user info from facebook after using oauth2 access_token

```
{
 ...
 "timezone": 5.5,
}
```

now I need to convert this to Zone Name to fill the openid connect zoneinfo filed.

```
ex : "Asia/Calcutta"
```

I am requesting from India , in timezone map I am seeing +05:30 is correct one. but facebook is issuing 5.5 I am not able solve this issue. please help me on this.

Comment: First of all, there is no 1:1 relation between offsets and time zones. There are multiple time zones using the same offset, so you can not get “the” time zone for a given offset. Second, what exactly is the problem relating `+05:30` to `5.5`? That `.5` corresponds to .5 * 60 minutes = `30` minutes should be pretty obvious, no?

Comment: hi @CBroe yes, I will take your suggestion, I just need to know, is that ok to do the .5*60 or not. now I will use that way. thank you

Comment: It depends on your programming language and your date-time API. The safe bet is if you can convert it into an offset from UTC rather than a time zone.

Comment: ok @OleV.V. sure I will try that as well. thank you

Comment: Would this question be helpful? [Convert UTC offset to timezone or date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820718/convert-utc-offset-to-timezone-or-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don’t know which language you’re after (if any particular). Here’s a Java solution:

```
    long secondsPerHour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1);
    long offsetSeconds = Math.round(5.5 * secondsPerHour);
    if (offsetSeconds < ZoneOffset.MIN.getTotalSeconds()
            || offsetSeconds > ZoneOffset.MAX.getTotalSeconds()) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid UTC offset, is out of range");
    } else {
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) offsetSeconds);
        System.out.println(offset);
    }
```

It prints

```
+05:30
```

You can use the `ZoneOffset` from this snippet anywhere a `ZoneId` is expected, since `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`. `ZoneId` is the modern Java class to represent a time zone.